# SQL Server - group by ID if column contains a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table:

```
ID   | NR | Status
1000 | 1  | A
1000 | 2  | A
1001 | 3  | A
1002 | 4  | A
1002 | 5  | N
1003 | 6  | N
```

I need to an output which groups these by `ID's`. The `NR` column can be ignored. If one of the records with those `ID's` contains Status A, That `status` will be given as result.

So my output would be:

```
ID   | Status
1000 | A 
1001 | A 
1002 | A 
1003 | N
```

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `MIN()` to pick minimum status value for each id, and A < N!

```
select id, min(status)
from tablename
group by id
```

Answer (score 5):

Although `min()` is the simplest method, it is not easily generalizable.  Another method is:

```
select id
       (case when sum(case when status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'A'
             else 'N' -- or whatever
        end) as status
from t
group by id;
```

Or, if you have a table with one row per `id`, then I would use `exists`:

```
select ids.id,
       (case when exists (select 1 from t where t.id = ids.id and t.status = 'A')
             then 'A' else 'N'
        end) as status
from ids;
```

This saves on the `group by` aggregation and can use an index on `(id, status)` for optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

You want exactly the records that match the predicate "If one of the records with those ID's contains Status A, that status will be given as result." ?
The query can be written simply as:

```
Select distinct ID, STATUS from [your working TABLE] where STATUS = 'A'.
```

Hope this can help.